# How to rewrite to a virtual directory with a different application

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a CMS application that manages multiple websites, today whenever i change the codebehind of one of these websites - i have to rebuild the dll for all websites, deploy it - this disconnects all current sessions and is really bad.

The iis is configured to listen to all domain requests, if the request is to one of the websites' domain , the application rewrites it, or example, if someone requests for http://www.example.com, and example.com is configured in the application to be website 12, it is rewritten to http://www.example.com/websites/12/default.aspx.

This is done for all websites.

We want to seperate the dlls of the websites from each other, and from the main CMS, we have a virtual directory to each websites, but when trying to rewrite to it, we discover that IIS support this (we get an "Could not load type '_12._Default'". error).

How can we perform this rewrite so it does rewrite to virtual directories, or if anyone has any other solution for the initial dll seperation problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easly do it with iis7

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility like http://iirf.codeplex.com to achieve this.  It's easy to install, improved over past versions, and the owner of the project does respond pretty quickly to questions.  Best of all, it's free, and supports global/virtual directory rewriting.

HTH.